# Microsoft Access 2010 - Recompile with new connectionString after db name and extension change

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have this old Access database (2000 format) which i want to convert to the new .accdb 2007 format. I know just basic stuff about Access so I knew it was a bit of a challenge, I decided to do it anyway.

It has two files, one appears to have all the tables "WOSS_Tables.mdb" (duh), the other ("WOSS.mdb") has a bunch of Forms and a Module and lots of code when I go to Database Tools / Visual Basic.

I opened them both in Access 2010 and did a  "Save and Publish", "Save ass .accdb" and everything went fine with that.

So the first thing that pops up when I open the WOSS.mdb is a Login Form, but when i try to log in it says:

[image: Error message]

So i get it, it does not find the new file. 
Digging into the WOSS.mdb file (Now WOSS.accdb) i find a Module which has sort of a connectionString named ruta (route in spanish), so i changed it, pointing it to my desktop for now:

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Public xdescripcion As String
'** Ruta para abrir la base de datos
'Public Const Ruta = "\\the_super_secret_old_route\"
Public Const Ruta = "C:\Users\AlexXPS\Desktop\Woss"
Public M
```

And found on a bunch of Forms, lines like these:

```
Set dbs = DBEngine.Workspaces(0).OpenDatabase(Ruta + "WOSS_Tables.mdb", False, False, "")
Set dbs = OpenDatabase(Ruta + "WOSS_Tables.mdb", False, False, "")
```

Updated those with "WOSS_Tables.accdb" aswell.

Now, I click Save, then Debug menu, Compile  then i close and reopen and i still get the same error as above, like it didnt compile at all?

If i check the Forms and the Module code, its like i changed it Ruta is correctly pointing at my desktop and the other changes were saved correctly aswell.

So, what am i doing wrong?

PS: Sorry for the long post :(

---

**EDIT!!!!!!!**

Okay, messing around with the code i found something out:

On the Logon screen theres a ComboBox which is supposed to show all the UserNames in the Users table, the ComboBox has a simple query on its "Row Source" Data Property

```
SELECT DISTINCTROW [Usuarios].[Name], [Usuarios].[Name] FROM Usuarios ORDER BY [Usuarios].[Name];
```

Which has nothing to do with the "Ruta" variable I changed!

So now the question is, how can I tell that ComboBox that the location of its source db changed? (Its not "\the_super_secret_old_route\WOSS_Tables.mdf" anymore, its "C:\Users\AlexXPS\Desktop\Woss/WOSS_Tables.accdb")

The previous error message was shown because of the ComboBox not finding the database :), not the other code (Which of course also needed to be changed)

I hope im explaining myself well, if not, heres a screenshot!

[image: Properties Window of ComboBox]

Comment: Do you have linked tables in the first db (WOSS.accdb)?

Comment: Nope, no tables there. And there's an Users table in the WOSS_Tables.accdb file which has all the users/passwords/other info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look again at the change you made to the *Ruta* constant.

```
'Public Const Ruta = "\\the_super_secret_old_route\"
Public Const Ruta = "C:\Users\AlexXPS\Desktop\Woss"
```

Notice the previous version ended with a backslash; the new version doesn't.  So in your `OpenDatabase()` statements, you're giving the full path to the database like this ...

```
"C:\Users\AlexXPS\Desktop\WossWOSS_Tables.mdb"
```

or maybe it's like this with your other changes ...

```
"C:\Users\AlexXPS\Desktop\WossWOSS_Tables.accdb"
```

Either way, it seems you're missing a backslash before the file name.

**Edit**:  Your updated question indicates you have this as the row source for a combo box:

```
SELECT DISTINCTROW [Usuarios].[Name], [Usuarios].[Name]
FROM Usuarios ORDER BY [Usuarios].[Name];
```

Open the navigation pane, right-click its header, then choose *Navigation Options ...*  Place a check mark in the box next to *Show Hidden Objects*.  Then verify there is a linked table named *Usuarios*.  You'll need to update the location of the db which contains the actual *Usuarios* source table.  Do that by selecting the *Database Tools* section of the ribbon, then choose *Linked Table Manager* to update the link's location.

**Edit2**: You can examine the `.Connect` property of the *Usuarios* link to determine the location of the db file which contains the source table.

```
Public Function BackEndLocation() As String
    BackEndLocation = Split(CurrentDb.TableDefs("Usuarios").Connect, "=")(1)
End Function
```

That way you might be able to get rid of the *Ruta* constant and avoid the need to update that constant and the name of the database file everywhere your code calls `OpenDatabase()`.  Just use the *Linked Table Manager* to update the links when the file name or location changes, then rely on the `BackEndLocation()` function to tell your code where it its.

Comment: Your're right! It was wrong, changed it. Thank you!
 Please see my edit above! :)

Comment: There is a *Usuarios* table in your database, perhaps as a local table but more likely a link to a table in the other database.  Perhaps you can't see it because it was set as hidden.  See the update to my answer for guidance about updating the link.

Comment: EXCELLENT! Updated every linked table to the new directory and now it works again! Thanks a lot HansUp :)! PS: When steve asked me if there were linked tables I assumed he meant normal tables on that accdb file, sorry about that Steve.. you had the right answer from the start!
Again thank you both for the help!

Comment: Yes, too many times it happened to me. That's why one day I hate Access. Its ability to hide things is unattainable. Next day I love it. That damn report done in 10 minutes.

Comment: Good!  I have one final suggestion.  Please see Edit2.

Comment: Nice indeed, i hate hard coded values like that. I'll definitely update the code according to edit2, thank you again HansUp and Steve!